# C - Programming an array to store words in a text document - malloc or dereferencing issue

Tags: c, malloc, dereference

I'm trying to read the words from a file word by word and store them in an array. I see that I'm looping through the words just fine, but then when I try to print the array, what it stores is not the words but something else. I think the problem is related to memory allocation or dereferencing pointers.

If I try to remove the * before data in the struct node, which is what I usually see in examples like this, all I get is null for all the values. Does anyone have any ideas on what might be wrong? I'm very new to C, so I understand the code is probably not that great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    char *data;
};

struct node *head, *ptr, *temp;

void display();
void words(char filename[]);

int main(void)
{
    char fname[99];

    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = NULL;
    head->next = NULL;

        printf("\nEnter file name: \n");
    scanf("%s", fname);
    words(fname);
    return 0;

}



void words(char filename[]){
    printf("o hi!, %s\n",filename);
    //open the file
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    char *word;
    char string[50];
    while (fgets(string,50,file)){
        word=strtok(string, " \n");
            do {
                printf("Oh hi!, %s\n",word);

                temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
                temp->data = word;
                temp->next = head->next;
                head->next = temp;

                printf("!!!%s\n",temp->data);
                //insert_front(word);
            } while (word=strtok(NULL," \n"));
    }
    display();
}


void display()
{
    ptr = head;
    while(ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
        printf("%s\n ", ptr->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither. More like a missing-malloc problem. You're only allocating space for the node; *not* the char data you're sucking out of your `string[50]` buffer with `strtok()`. The `char*` your storing in each node points to memory in the stack variable `string[50]`, which is overwritten with each new `fgets()` call. For what it is worth, there are *much* easier ways to do this than you're presenting, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp->data = word;
```

lets `temp->data` point into the `string` array. When you call `fgets` the next time, the contents of `string` are overwritten, and the node in the list points still at the same place in the array, which now no longer contains the token. You need to copy the token,

```
temp->data = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
strcpy(temp->data,word);
```

to have it persist past the current iteration of the loop.

Comment: +1, although I myself prefer the short-hand version of this (`strdup()`), it is not part of the standard library. All the answers presented here will likely work, but this one will work everywhere, posix-system or not.

Answer (score 1):

When you are setting word = strtok(string, "\n") that is problematic, because string is a local variable and strtok will just give you a pointer inside of that local array.

Try `word = strdup(strtok(string, " \n"));`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
temp->data = word;
```

to

```
temp->data = strdup(word); /* Or use malloc and strcpy if it is not implemented on your platform*/
```

This will fill the `data` item of the node with a new pointer with a copy to the word.